# How to get json value in js code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json code and i want get json value `units_num` in alert jQuery. How can don it?

My json code:

```
[{"id":"11","name":"hiih","units_num":00}]
```

I tried as in js code: **http://jsfiddle.net/Wj8ZL/**

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('[{"id":"11","name":"hiih","units_num":00}]');
alert(obj['units_num']); // This don't work

var t = JSON.parse('[{"id":"11","name":"hiih","units_num":00}]');
alert(t['units_num']) // This don't work
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your json contains an array of objects, even if there is only one in there. So you need to access that first object in the array

```
var obj = $.parseJSON('[{"id":"11","name":"hiih","units_num":"00"}]');
alert(obj[0]['units_num']);
```

Comment: @Taylor, To add to this answer: `var obj = [{"id":"11","name":"hiih","units_num": 0}]; alert(obj[0]['units_num']);` is also valid. You only need to use `$.parseJSON` or `JSON.parse`, if you are getting your JSON in the form of a string.

Answer (score 1):

@TravisJ gave a big part of the issue, the other one being quite easy to spot if you read the error log:

```
"units_num":00
```

is not valid. It should read

```
"units_num":0
```